# Encoutering an error 'run executed for function module' while calling function

Tags: sas, sas-iml

I wrote one module in proc iml and trying to call it using call fuctiong and supplied parameters.

But its throwing the erorr: 
run executed for function module.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please include the code that you wrote that caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that you have defined a function that returns a value ('function module') so you need to call it like this:
x = MyFunction(x,y,z);

You cannot use the CALL statement to call a function, only to call subroutines that do not return values.